# Error while creating bootable media of Windows 10 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: live-usb, windows-10, iso

I am using `woeusb` program and when I choose Windows 10 iso file that I have downloaded from Microsoft site and choose my USB drive then hit install it gives me this error:

[image]

THANKS in advance :D

Comment: Since some time ago only MKUSB works. Somehow Microsft changed the format as to not allow the usual tools to work

Comment: should i use MKUSB program to do something ?